# Xcode 6.1.1 iOS simulator error: -[Purchase superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am developing an iOS app using Xcode 6.1.1. When I press a button on my main ViewController, “ViewController”, it is supposed to modal segue to a second, “Purchase”. However, the app crashes on the iOS simulator. I have tried cleaning my project, restarting Xcode, and deleting non-existent connections in the .storyboard. However, nothing seems to work. Also, "All Exceptions" in the breakpoints are turned on. Here is the code for Purchase.m:

```
#import "Introduction.h"
#import "Purchase.h"
#define ProductID = “IAP_ID"

@interface Purchase ()



@end

@implementation Purchase

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Adding activity indicator
activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
activityIndicatorView.center = self.view.center;
[activityIndicatorView hidesWhenStopped];
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicatorView];
[activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
//Hide purchase button initially
purchaseButton.hidden = YES;
[self fetchAvailableProducts];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)fetchAvailableProducts{
NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet
                             setWithObjects:@“IAP_ID",nil];
productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                   initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
productsRequest.delegate = self;
[productsRequest start];
}

- (BOOL)canMakePurchases
{
return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}
- (void)purchaseMyProduct:(SKProduct*)product{
if ([self canMakePurchases]) {
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
else{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                              @"Purchases are disabled in your device"     message:nil delegate:
                              self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:     nil];
    [alertView show];
}
}
-(IBAction)purchase:(id)sender{
[self purchaseMyProduct:[validProducts objectAtIndex:0]];
purchaseButton.enabled = NO;
}

#pragma mark StoreKit Delegate

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
    switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
            NSLog(@"Purchasing");
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier
                 isEqualToString:@"9plus10equals21"]) {
                NSLog(@"Purchased ");
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                                          @"Purchase is completed succesfully"     message:nil delegate:
                                          self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"     otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alertView show];
            }
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            NSLog(@"Restored ");
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            NSLog(@"Purchase failed ");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request
didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
int count = [response.products count];
if (count>0) {
    validProducts = response.products;
    validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([validProduct.productIdentifier
         isEqualToString:@“IAP_ID"]) {
        [productTitleLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                    @"Product Title:     %@",validProduct.localizedTitle]];
        [productDescriptionLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                          @"Product Desc:     %@",validProduct.localizedDescription]];
        [productPriceLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                    @"Product Price: %@",validProduct.price]];
    }
} else {
    UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                        initWithTitle:@"Not Available"
                        message:@"No products to purchase"
                        delegate:self
                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                        otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [tmp show];
}    
[activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
purchaseButton.hidden = NO;
}

@end
```

Here is the error message:

```
2015-03-01 11:58:00.460 Phone hack prank [7758:357987] [RevMob] Starting       RevMobAds
2015-03-01 11:58:01.481 Phone hack prank [7758:357987] Session started with     block
2015-03-01 11:58:01.481 Phone hack prank [7758:357987] [RevMob] Initializating    Banner.
2015-03-01 11:58:01.481 Phone hack prank [7758:357987] [RevMob] Requesting  banner data.
2015-03-01 11:58:02.638 Phone hack prank [7758:357987] -[Purchase superview]:     unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a177c70
(lldb)
```

Comment: I am pretty sure there is problem with activity indicator, 
when you present view controller, you should remove activity indicator and alert view first.
reply if it works

Comment: I tried removing them, but it still crashes